# How do I access a variable, created outside of an IF/ELSE scope, update it in the IF statement, and access that update in the ELSE statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, variables

Sorry, I'm not sure how else to word my question and, as such, am having a hard time finding any relevant solutions.

**The Project**

I'm creating a script that cleans batches of raw text from an Excel file...

[image]

...gathers each "cell" into an array, and pushes each "person" into a new array while attaching their respective bits of info to each person. The text itself contains things like first names, last names, and cities. Some people have multiple cities on new lines...

[image]

**All info is randomly generated and any real life comparisons are purely coincidental*

**The Problem**

I'm able to clean the text up and dump the contents of each line to an array without any issues but the problem comes when I try to push "lines" that only have a city to the most recent "full person". For instance:

> John Doe has lived in Anchorage, AK; New York, NY; and Des Moines, IA.

New York, NY and Des Moines, IA each end up on their own separate lines with each city being the only item in an array.

When I go to push a city into the new array I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
```

**The Code**

Here's the code I'm working with. Specifically, my issue is with the `mergeSort(a)` function:

```js
function sanitize(rawData) { // Accessed from event handler on line 70
  // Split the raw data into "lines"
  const splitByLine = rawData.split("\n");

  // Split each line into an array by "tabs"
  const splitByTab = splitByLine.map(line => {
    return line.split("\t");
  });

  // Trim each array cell and remove any empty cells
  const cleaned = splitByTab.map(function(item) {
    const scrubbed = item.map(chunk => {
      return chunk.trim();
    });

    const trimmed = scrubbed.filter(chunk => {
      return chunk !== "";
    });

    return trimmed;
  });

  // Remove any empty arrays
  const droppedEmpties = cleaned.filter(arrayItem => {
    return arrayItem.length > 0;
  });

  mergeSort(droppedEmpties); // Line 32
}

// Sort cities lived in for each person
function mergeSort(a) {
  console.log(a);

  function Person(firstName, lastName, gender, city, birthday) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.city = [city];
    this.birthday = birthday;
  }

  const people = [];

  let toggleID = 0;

  a.forEach(person => {
    // If the entry is likely to be a person...
    if (person.length > 1) {
      // Set the ID for the last known person
      toggleID = a.indexOf(person);

      let newPerson = new Person(
        person[0], // firstName
        person[1], // lastName
        person[2], // gender
        person[3], // city
        person[4] // birthday
      );

      people.push(newPerson);
      console.log(people[toggleID]);
    } else { // ...Else assume it's a city and push to the previous person.
      people[toggleID].city.push(person[0]); // THROWS ERROR: Cannot read property of 'city' of undefined
    }
  });
}

// Get form submission
document.getElementById("my-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const textarea = document.getElementById("my-textarea");
  const rawData = textarea.value;
  sanitize(rawData); // Line 1
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="my-form">
    <button>Submit</button>
    <textarea id="my-textarea" cols="150" rows="15">
Cynthia Hogsett Female Grand Rapids, MI 12/6/1983
Jacqueline Crosborne Female Syracuse, NY 3/19/1984
Ricky Johnson Male Tioga, ND 4/6/1972
Jimmy Jessup Male Ames, IA 10/27/1993
            Williston, ND 
            Grand Forks, ND 
Andrew Manchez Male El Paso, TX 3/1/2001
Sarah Smith Female Seattle, WA 7/19/1981
Esteban Faccin Male Gilbert, AZ 1/30/1973
            Spokane, WA 
            Minot, ND 
            James Town, CO 
                </textarea>
  </form>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My guess is that, although I'm defining let `toggleID` outside of the `IF/ELSE` scope, I can't mutate the value in the `IF statement` and access that updated value from within the `ELSE statement`.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `if` block and the `else` block don't execute at the same time, so you need to hope that `toggleID` has been set in some *previous iteration* of the loop. That's hard to guarantee. But actually that's not your problem, `toggleID` is set as you expect it. The problem is rather that when one of the element is not a person that gets pushed to `people`, in the subsequent run the next person does get `pushed` to the next free index. Not to `toggleID`. You should see `console.log(people[toggleID]);` (inside the `if` block) logging `undefined` even *before* it throws the exception.

`a.indexOf(person)` (or better, the second argument of the `forEach` callback) will refer to the last index seen in the original `a` array, not the `people` array that's relevant for getting the previous person. Using it to index into `people` will occasionally come up with the wrong (no) result - as you don't create exactly one new person for each element in `a`, every time.

Instead, you can

- not store a `toggleID` at all, but just dynamically look up the last element in the array using `people[people.length-1]` every time.
- not store the index, but just the last `newPerson` object that you created.
- get the correct index, e.g. by doing `toggleID = people.length` before the `people.push(…)`, or by doing `toggleID = people.push(…) - 1;`

Comment: You were right on the money. I feel a bit silly for having been so hung up on something that seems so obvious. I dropped the [toggleID] bit and started pushing to people[people.length-1] as you suggested and it all fell into place.

I appreciate you taking the time to type up a response, thank you so much!